# Link Table via DAO

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

So I am essentially trying to link a table via DAO from an ACCDB that is password-encrypted into the DB I am working in.  The premise of what I am doing is that the data is sort of "user sensitive" so I do not want to let every user have access to this table in my front end (have the front-end/back-end split), only specific users.  What I would like to do is to check the username of the computer, then allow the front-end to link to the data if the username is correct:

```
Select Case Environ("username") 'select case user environment name

Case "jsmith" 'if username is jsmith then
Set db = DAO.OpenDatabase("Audit.accdb", False, False, _
";pwd=adaudit12") 'create connection to my other db
Set tbl = db.TableDefs(14) 'selects the table via index
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tbl 'create a link to my current DB with this table (throws ex here)

Case Else

End Select
```

This returns runtime error '3367' Cannot Append. An object with that name already exists in the collection.

So I thought to do this:

```
For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
Msgbox tbl
Next tbl
```

But the table doesnt exist in my database, so what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at how you're examining the table names in `CurrentDb`.  This line throws error #13, *"Type mismatch"*, on my system:

```vb
Msgbox tbl
```

I think you should ask for the TableDef.Name instead:

```vb
Msgbox tbl.Name
```

However, I'm not sure that's the only problem here.  You seem to be trying to link to a table in another db file by copying that `TableDef` and adding it to `CurrentDb.TableDefs`.  ***IF*** you can make that work, it won't give you a *link* to the source table, it would make a new *copy* in `CurrentDb`.  But I'm skeptical whether it can work at all.

You could create a new `TableDef` object, set its `Name`, `Connect`, and `SourceTableName` properties, then append it to `CurrentDb.TableDefs`.  Include the database password in the `Connect` property.

Here is code tested in Access 2007.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strDbFile As String
Dim strLinkName As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strSourceTableName As String

strDbFile = "C:\share\Access\MyDb.accdb"
strPassword = "foo"
strSourceTableName = "Contacts"
strLinkName = "link_to_contacts"

strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & _
    ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile
Debug.Print strConnect
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef
tdf.Connect = strConnect
tdf.SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
tdf.Name = strLinkName
db.TableDefs.Append tdf
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: See mwolfe02's warnings about query name conflict and the insecurity of `Environ("username")`.

Comment: Good point about how the OP was trying to copy the TableDef object itself.  I glossed over the code and only really addressed the error message.

Comment: @HansUp I came up with that code after reading some articles;  they said that was to link the table, but it didnt look like it did so I was sort of skeptical.  Is there a better way to link this data? Rather than **appending** it into a table

Comment: @JasonBayldon: What HansUp shows in his code sample is the standard way to link tables programmatically in Access.  Keep in mind you are not actually appending a physical table, but rather a table *definition*.  The table definition contains both the schema and a pointer to the location of the physical table.  The physical table may be located within the current database (a local table) or, as in this case, it may be located in an external location (a linked table).

Answer (score 2):

**Tables and queries share the same name space in MS Access**.  Chances are you have a query with the same name as the table you are trying to link.

Also, `Environ("username")` is easily spoofed.  Consider using the API function [GetUserName](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetUserName.shtml) instead.  Of course, if you need real security you'll want to upgrade your back-end to SQL Server (Express) or some other RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, there is no object in the DB with the same name.  Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely start using the API function.