# Link two Microsoft Access tables via vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to link two tables in different databases. What I've done is create a new table and then try to change the DESCRIPTION property to a path of a specific table in the other Database.

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
thepath = "DATABASE=P:\Cadworx P&ID Implementation\3 Piping\P&IDs Jesus Test\Testproject\myTest.mdb;TABLE=Service"

Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs("ThisTable")

On Error Resume Next

tdf.Properties("Description") = "DATABASE=P:\Cadworx P&ID Implementation\3 Piping\P&IDs Jesus Test\Testproject\myTest.mdb;TABLE=Service"

If Err.Number = 3270 Then
Set prp = tdf.CreateProperty("Description", _
    dbText, thepath)
tdf.Properties.Append prp
End If
```

This hasn't given me the desired results, as the link is never established. Can someone please tell me if this is the right way to do this or if there is a better way? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Description has nothing, really nothing to do with the description of your problem!

Comment: Cisco, I understand. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link Table via DAO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932353/link-table-via-dao)

Comment: If you search just that little, you could find out, so I voted for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strDbFile As String
Dim strConnect As String
Dim strSourceTableName As String
Dim strLinkName As String
Dim f As Object
Dim varfile As Variant

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)   'Windows Explorer, 3 means file picker.  4 Is for folder, 1 to open dialog box, 2 to save as
f.show                              'Show Windows explorer

With f
f.allowmultiselect = False
For Each varfile In .selecteditems
    strDbFile = varfile                     'File selected assigned to   source database file
Next
End With

strSourceTableName = "Service"                                                                      'Source Table
strLinkName = "Service"                                                                          'Final table name once link has been established

strConnect = "MS Access;PWD=" & strPassword & ";DATABASE=" & strDbFile

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set tdf = dbs.CreateTableDef

tdf.Connect = strConnect                                                                           'Establish link between databases
tdf.SourceTableName = strSourceTableName
tdf.Name = strLinkName
dbs.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

As Gustav said, the solution was along what he posted. New to access so I didn't really know what the DAO library is. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can link to tables from other Access databases fairly easily using Access' in-built features.

Depending on the version of Access you're using, there should be an option to import/link to other data sources, including another Access database:

[image]

This starts an import/link wizard. Browse to the database file you want to link to:

[image]

Specify whether you want to import or link to data objects within the database file you browsed to (in this case, link):

[image]

Select the objects you want to link to:

[image]

Linked objects will appear in your navigation pane with a blue arrow denoting they are a linked object, rather than something stored locally to your current database:

[image]

You should then be able to use your linked tables as if they were any other kind of table in your database.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your response, but I want to do it in an userform so that the user can select the source database file and then it would do everything for him. I was able to do it through VBA.