# can a create a linked table from one Access DB to another DB via VBScript?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I just can use VBscript. My ACCESS database is version 2013.

I have a source MS Access database with a table named "SourceTbl". Right now, I would like to write a vbscript such that a destination MS Access database can create a linked table of "SourceTbl".

I have tried to google the answer. But seem that it could not. Anyone can help? Thank you in advance.

The code that I have tried is by using DAO to open the 2 databases and then try to use docmd.transferdatabase as well as TableDefs.Append. But both properties seem could not be used in VBScript:

```
strDbPath = "c:\temp\sourceDB.accdb"
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set wrkJet = dbe.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", 2) ' dbUseJet = 2
Set db = wrkJet.OpenDatabase(strDbPath, True, False)

strDbPath2 = "c:\temp\destDB.accdb"
Set dbe2 = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set wrkJet2 = dbe2.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", 2) ' dbUseJet = 2
Set db2 = wrkJet2.OpenDatabase(strDbPath2, True, False)

'I tried to use transferDatabase
dbe2.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "c:\temp\sourceDB.accdb", acTable, "sourceTbl", "sourceTbl"

'Or use TableDefs, but both not work
db2.TableDefs.Append db.tabledefs("SourceTbl")

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set wrkJet = Nothing
Set dbe = Nothing

db2.Close
Set db2 = Nothing
Set wrkJet2 = Nothing
Set dbe2 = Nothing
```

** Part 2 - I tried to use "createTableDef", however, error was shown: "No field defined--cannot append TableDef or Index"

```
strDbPath = "c:\temp\sourceDB.accdb"
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set wrkJet = dbe.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", 2) ' dbUseJet = 2
Set db = wrkJet.OpenDatabase(strDbPath, True, False)

strDbPath2 = "c:\temp\destDB.accdb"
Set dbe2 = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set wrkJet2 = dbe2.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", 2) ' dbUseJet = 2
Set db2 = wrkJet2.OpenDatabase(strDbPath2, True, False)

set tdf = db2.createtabledef("sourceTbl")
tdf.connect = db.connect
tdf.sourcetablename = "sourceTbl"
db2.TableDefs.Append tdf

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set wrkJet = Nothing
Set dbe = Nothing

db2.Close
Set db2 = Nothing
Set wrkJet2 = Nothing
Set dbe2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Please post a code that you have tried

Comment: Please update the original post. This is unreadable :)

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar Many thanks for your guidance. :)

Comment: You're on the right track with DAO, but you'll have to call `CreateTableDef`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933105/3820271

Comment: @andre   : many thanks! Look good, will try the codes. Just one quick question: the code in the link you provided is using vba, and in vbscript,  there is no "currentDB", how to cater that?

Comment: `DBEngine(0)(0)` should be good for CurrentDb which really is `Application.CurrentDb`.

Comment: You already have the database variable: `db2` - use this (the target DB).

Comment: it shows error: "No field defined--cannot append TableDef or Index.`code` set tdf = db2.CreateTableDef
`code` tdf.Connect = db.connect
`code` tdf.SourceTableName = "sourceTbl"
`code` tdf.Name = "sourceTbl"
db2.TableDefs.Append tdf

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you are trying. Code in comments doesn't really work.

Comment: @Andre: I updated my question. Thank for your remind.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure `db.connect` contains the correct string? Please add `Debug.Print db.connect` before using it and add the output to the question.

Comment: @Andre: I used msgbox instead of debug.print as it is vbscript, not VBA. The result is return "NULL". Does it mean I haven't connect to the target db actually?

Comment: No, it just means that property isn't set. If you didn't get an error on `OpenDatabase` I'd say you are connected. Try using this: `tdf.connect = ";DATABASE=" & strDbPath`

Comment: @Andre: It works! Thanks! However, the result is, the destination database has a physical table in it. Instead, what I want is a link table which points to sourceDB's sourceTBL.Do you have any idea on that? Many thanks!!

Comment: Why do you think it is a physical table? I have trouble imagining how this operation could copy instead of link the table. If you open DestDB in Access, it should have the "linked table" icon: http://theitservice.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Access-linked-tables.jpg -- and the ultimate test: move/rename SourceDB, and then try to access the table in DestDB. That should fail.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, you are correct. It is a linked table, not a copied table. The case has been perfectly resolved. Thank you very much for all of your guys help!